# Java Drag&Drop (Transferable) issue on Visual Studio 10

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I have a program which contain a JTable where I can drag and drop the cell data into an external IDE

My Transferable class supports two Data Flavors

1. `DataFlavor.stringFlavor`
2. `CUST_FLAVOR` (a custom data flavor used within the application)

When I try to drag and drop a cell data into Eclipse/Wordpad, its work fine. JVM will call `getTransferData()` for `stringFlavor`.
But when I try to drag and drop into Visual studio 10 interface, the JVM will call `getTransferData()` for both `stringFlavor` and `CUST_FLAVOR`. I don't know why this is happening only with Visual Studio 10 Interface. I tried with Visual Studio 2005 and there is no issue.

Below is my code

If I try to copy into a wordpad it prints (on system.out)
*getTransferData flavor = Unicode String*

but, in Visual Studio 10, it prints (on system.out)
*getTransferData flavor = Unicode String

getTransferData flavor = CUST_FLAVOR*

In the `getTransferData()` method, if it is a `CUST_FLAVOR` flavor then it has to return a object which is not `Serializable` and hence it will throw a `NotSerializableException`.

Now how do I restrict the JVM not to call `getTransferData()` for `CUST_FLAVOR` when I try to drag and drop into Visual Studio?

```
public class DragDropTest extends JPanel{
    private JTable table;
    public static final DataFlavor CUST_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(File.class, "CUST_FLAVOR");

    DragDropTest(){
        table = new JTable(5, 1);
        table.getModel().setValueAt("Data 1", 0, 0);
        table.getModel().setValueAt("Data 2", 1, 0);
        table.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(){
            public int getSourceActions(JComponent c){
                return COPY;
            }

            protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent component){
                TableModel model = ((JTable)component).getModel();
                Transferable transferable=new GenericTransferable(
                    model.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn()));
                return transferable;
            }

        class GenericTransferable implements Transferable{
            private String str;
            public GenericTransferable(Object str){
                this.str = str.toString();}
            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors(){
                return new DataFlavor[]{DataFlavor.stringFlavor, CUST_FLAVOR};}
            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor){
                return flavor.equals(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) || flavor.equals(CUST_FLAVOR);}
            public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)throws UnsupportedFlavorException{
                System.out.println("getTransferData flavor = " + flavor.getHumanPresentableName());
                if (flavor.equals(CUST_FLAVOR)) {
                    return new Object();
                }
                else if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                    return str;
                }
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
                }
            }
        });

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
        table.setDragEnabled(true);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DragAndDropTest");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DragDropTest(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks

-rooble

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).